# Convert comma separated list into JSON using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, csv

How do you convert a comma separated list into json using Javascript / jQuery?

e.g.

Convert the following:

```
var names = "Mark,Matthew,Luke,John,";
```

into:

```
var jsonified = {
    names: [
      {name: "Mark"},
      {name: "Mattew"},
      {name: "Luke"},
      {name: "John"}
    ]
  };
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var jsonfied = {
    names: names.replace( /,$/, "" ).split(",").map(function(name) {
        return {name: name};
    })
};
```

result of stringfying jsonfied:

```
JSON.stringify( jsonfied );

{
    "names": [{
        "name": "Mark"
    }, {
        "name": "Matthew"
    }, {
        "name": "Luke"
    }, {
        "name": "John"
    }]
}
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/H8c4n/)

Comment: Added a demo to your answer, I hope you like it, you can rollback if you don't.