# Create nested Javascript Object dynamically

Tags: javascript, json, string

I have got a `.` (dot) separated string, from which I want to create nested JSON object. The length of the string is not fixed. For example,

```
var string = 'a.b.c.d';
```

Then my JSON object should be as following:

```
a: {
    b: {
        c:{
           d: {
                  //Some properties here. 
              }
          } 
    }
}
```

I've tried following code:

```
var packageName = "a.b.c.d"
var splitted = packageName.split('.');
var json = {};
for(var i=0;i<splitted.length-1;i++){
    json[splitted[i]] = splitted[i+1];
}
```

But this returns

```
{
    a: 'b', 
    b: 'c',
    c: 'd'
}
```

But this is not what I want. I've also searched on google and found similar questions, but **no solutions answer my problem.** For example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441458/convert-comma-separated-list-into-json-using-javascript).

Comment: You're asking how to create a nested JS object, not JSON. To create JSON would be to create your JS object, and then serialize it to the JSON text format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new object each time and attribute it to the last object created. And it goes until `splitted.length`, not `splitted.length - 1`, because you're using `<`, not `<=`.

```js
var packageName = "a.b.c.d";
var splitted = packageName.split('.');
var json = {};
var current = json;
for (var i = 0; i < splitted.length; i++) {
    current[splitted[i]] = {};
    current = current[splitted[i]];
}
console.log(json);
```

Comment: correct! I didn't just think of this simple logic. Thanks . +1 and accept!

Answer (score 3):

A good use case for `reduce`

```js
packageName = "a.b.c.d";
initProps = {hi: 'there'};

obj = packageName.split('.').reduceRight((o, x) => ({[x]: o}), initProps);

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

If you find loops easier to work with, a loop could be written concisely as

```
result = {};
ptr = result;

for (let prop of packageName.split('.'))
    ptr = ptr[prop] = {};
```

Comment: Thanks for alternative. But it's quite difficult for me to understand this. +1.

Comment: Excellent use case for `reduce[Right]`. So many nasty and incomprehensible examples of functional programming get posted here, especially with `reduce`, it's nice to see clean, clear, idiomatic examples.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the last splittted part as property for some payload.

I suggest to keep the object reference and use a temporary variable for aceessing an creating a new property, if necessary.

Please avoid the use of [JSON](http://json.org/) for not stringified objects.

```js
var packageName = "a.b.c.d",
    splitted = packageName.split('.'),
    result = {},
    temp = result,
    i;
  
for (i = 0; i < splitted.length - 1; i++) {
   temp[splitted[i]] = temp[splitted[i]] || {};
   temp = temp[splitted[i]];
}

temp[splitted[i]] = { some: 'data' };

console.log(result);
```